# How do I remove white thread flakes from my jacket?

Tags: clothing, water, winter, stain

I have an Adidas100% Polyester jacket of black colour. It is warm in nature and used during mild winters.

My mother happen to wash it along with other coloured clothes due to which it has developed small white thread type sticky on it.

Is there a way to remove them completely?

Comment: Could we get a picture, please?

Answer (score 4):

For removing hair and fluff from garments I find it effective to wind sellotape/scotch/parcel tape around my hand, sticky side out, and then pat the garment down. It may be easier to wear it or lay it out flat on a fluff free surface.

If it's likely that this item will find its way into the wash again with the same item that caused the problem perhaps try turning your jacket inside out before washing, or put it inside one of those synthetic net bags with a plastic zip

Comment: Great answer! I do essentially the same thing with a "lint roller". Lots of companies sell them inexpensively. It's one of my primary lifehack tools.

Comment: Lint rollers are great and i should have mentioned one- thought in the spirit of lifehacks I should go for something a bit more hacky :) - indeed with practice it becomes possible to apply the tape to your hand just loose enough that (with suitably dry hands) you can rub the hand along the garment and the tape will roll around your hand just like a lint roller

Comment: I use a similar technique but hold a length of tape stretched out between two hands, patting the fabric until it loses its stickiness, and continue with another strip. It's easy to keep it tangle free when the tape reel is on a dispenser.